# Keeping track of wins Rock paper scissors

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a rock paper scissors game in `Javascript`. I have gotten to a point where the code can figure out who wins ,the computer or you.

**I am stuck at the following:** I can't keep track of how many times I have won and I want the game to end after 5 tries. Then it outputs how many times I have won out of 5 games.

**My Javascript code is below:**

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.33) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.66) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
    var counter =0;
    document.getElementById("box1").onclick= function(){
        if(computerChoice == "rock"){
            alert("It is a tie, You chose Rock, computer chose Rock, Lame!");
        }
        else if(computerChoice =="paper"){
            alert("Sucker, YOU LOST! You chose Rock, COMPUTER OVERLORD chose paper");
        }
        else if(computerChoice=="scissors"){
            alert("DANG! You Beat Computer OVERLORD cuz he chose scissors");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("box2").onclick= function(){
        if(computerChoice == "paper"){
            alert("It is a tie, You chose Paper, computer chose Paper, Lame!");
        }
        else if(computerChoice =="scissors"){
            alert("Sucker, YOU LOST! You chose Paper, COMPUTER OVERLORD chose scissors");
        }
        else if(computerChoice=="rock"){
            alert("DANG! You Beat Computer OVERLORD cuz he chose rock");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("box3").onclick= function(){
        if(computerChoice == "scissors"){
            alert("It is a tie, You chose scissors, computer chose scissors, Lame!");
        }
        else if(computerChoice =="rock"){
            alert("Sucker, YOU LOST! You chose scissors, COMPUTER OVERLORD chose rock");
        }
        else if(computerChoice=="paper"){
            alert("DANG! You Beat Computer OVERLORD cuz he chose paper");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    i++;
    return counter;
}
var computerWins = 5-counter;
if (computerWins > counter) {
    console.log("COMPUTER OVERLORD WINS, HE IS YOUR MASTER!");
}
else {
    console.log("Hey computer overlord and you can be friends, just dont tell anyone you lost, k");
}
</script>
```

Comment: define the counter outside the for

Comment: You do not update the computer choice. It will generate a choice once, and then reuse it every time, which is incorrect.

Comment: Can you give examples of what/where I need to write the code please?

Answer (score 2):

This requires some variables (`round, human, computer`) which have a [global scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and live outside of the `onClick` method's lifecycle. Update these variables accordingly after every `onClick` event finishes. Note the `updateRound` method I created to accomplish this.

Given that the function performed in each `onClick` method is logically equivalent, it is best to extract it to a function to adhere to the programming's **Do not Repeat Yourself [(DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)** dogma.

There is also another possible logic error in your code. As it sits, the computer's decision will be the same for all 5 games. To update the computer's decision every round, it is necessary to wrap the "computer choice" logic in a function which can be triggered every round.

Here is a more elegant [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spencerdcarlson/k7w03mLL/3/) solution

```js
var counter = 0;
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.66) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}

document.getElementById("box1").onclick = function() {
  var victor = 'COMPUTER OVERLORD';
  if (computerChoice == "rock") {
    victor = 'draw';
    alert("It is a tie, You chose Rock, computer chose Rock, Lame!");
  } else if (computerChoice == "paper") {
    alert("Sucker, YOU LOST! You chose Rock, COMPUTER OVERLORD chose paper");
  } else if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
    victor = 'HUMAN';
    alert("DANG! You Beat Computer OVERLORD cuz he chose scissors");
  }
  updateRound(victor);
}
document.getElementById("box2").onclick = function() {
  var victor = 'COMPUTER OVERLORD';
  if (computerChoice == "paper") {
    victor = 'draw';
    alert("It is a tie, You chose Paper, computer chose Paper, Lame!");
  } else if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
    alert("Sucker, YOU LOST! You chose Paper, COMPUTER OVERLORD chose scissors");
  } else if (computerChoice == "rock") {
    victor = 'HUMAN';
    alert("DANG! You Beat Computer OVERLORD cuz he chose rock");
  }
  updateRound(victor);
}
document.getElementById("box3").onclick = function() {
  var victor = 'COMPUTER OVERLORD';
  if (computerChoice == "scissors") {
    victor = 'draw';
    alert("It is a tie, You chose scissors, computer chose scissors, Lame!");
  } else if (computerChoice == "rock") {
    alert("Sucker, YOU LOST! You chose scissors, COMPUTER OVERLORD chose rock");
  } else if (computerChoice == "paper") {
    victor = 'HUMAN';
    alert("DANG! You Beat Computer OVERLORD cuz he chose paper");
  }
  updateRound(victor);
}

var round = 0;
var human = 0;
var computer = 0;
var maxGames = 5;

function updateRound(victor) {
  round = round + 1;
  if (victor == "HUMAN") {
    human = human + 1;
  } else if (victor == 'COMPUTER OVERLORD') {
    computer = computer + 1;
  } else {
 // It was a draw
  }
  if (round >= maxGames) {
    alert('You have won ' + human + ' out of ' + round + ' games.');
    // reset the score
    round = 0;
    human = 0;
    computer = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id='box1'>Rock</button>
  <button id='box2'>Paper</button>
  <button id='box3'>Scissors</button>
</body>
</html>
```